# How to use Common Table Expression properly - Example where it seems to be very slow in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, cte, temporary-tables

I've been starting using common table expressions more and more and thought I was using them "right" but I've run into an example where the solution with CTE is very slow compared to using a temp table. I will put the two examples below, the first one using common table expressions takes a very long time to run (3min 27sec) and the second one using temp tables which only takes 0:50. Is this an inappropriate way to use CTE or am I implementing it poorly?

```
;WITH tmpRiskFactor AS  --Super slow. 3:27
(SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM [tablevaluedfunction]() )
(SELECT DISTINCT col1 AS [RiskFactors] FROM tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col4 FROM tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col5 FROM tmpRiskFactor
) AS tmp;
```

Using temp:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 INTO #tmpRiskFactor FROM [tablevaluedfunction]() --A lot faster. 0:50
SELECT * INTO #RiskFactors FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT col1 AS [RiskFactors] FROM #tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col2  FROM #tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col3 FROM #tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col4 FROM #tmpRiskFactor
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT col5 FROM #tmpRiskFactor
) AS tmp;
```

Comment: You are calling a table valued function 5 times when using the CTE, but only once when using the temp table.  This is the most likely reason for the slowness.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit more on Jonathan's comment, each time you reference a CTE, the query within the CTE will be called.

Each `UNION` you are using is creating a separate execution of the CTE, thereby executing the table value function each time as well. By putting the results into a temp table, you are only then reading the static data in the temp table for each `UNION` and avoid recalculating the data.

If you check the execution plan for each of the queries, you'll be able to see a visual confirmation of this fact.

In your case, it makes much more sense to use a temp table as illustrated by the vastly different execution times. I personally find non-recursive CTEs rarely offer much by way of performance and are usually more helpful for readability  and logical separation of query contents.

Comment: I second the last sentence with exception of recursive CTE and use with window functions.

Comment: @BobKlimes Great point, edited to specify non-recursive. Thanks

Comment: "*the query within the CTE will be called*" - doesn't SQL Server cache the results of the CTE somehow? (Postgres and Oracle will do that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, there is no  such caching in SQL Server. Oracle and (recently, and I think for now it's not by default) Postgres materialize CTEs into temp tables.